# Uncheck billing and shipping address during checkout in onestep checkout?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I am using magetop one-step checkout. When i login to store and click on place order button the billing and shipping address checkbox automatically checked .if guest customer or new customer with first time purchase will not see this issue

Any solution or direction for it?